# Python Problem with using imported module

Tags: python

Im a newbie in coding and decided to learn python as my first language.
Right now, Im trying to create a bot which, among other things, opens a https URL automatically. In the tuturial im watching, the module "requests" is used. I installed this module with pip3 over the Command Prompt of windows. I got it to install (or atleast I think so (I followed this tuturial to do so https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdJywzSCGbc)), so now when I type "import requests" into the Command Prompt there is no more error message telling me there is no such
module.
But when I type import requests in my bot.py file on pycharm the error message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'keeps poping up and I can´t execute my code. Any idea what went wrong here or/and how I can use the downloaded requests module?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On pycharm there is a tab called "Python packages". It is at the bottom of the screen. When you click on it a whole tab with modules appear. Just search the requests module and click on install.

This is what worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. This made everything a lot less complicated. The module works now :)